# Prove that the mapping from $G$ to $G^*$ defined by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$ is an isomorphism from $G$ onto $G^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$, define a new group $G^*$ that has the same elements as $G$ with the operation $*$ defined by $a*b = ba$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $G^*$.

Prove that the mapping from $G$ to $G^*$ defined by $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$ is an isomorphism from $G$ onto $G^*$.

I don't even know where to start with this "new group".

Comment: Well, can you show that it is a group?

Answer (score 2):

First, check injectivity:

$$ \phi(x) = \phi(y) \implies x^{-1} = y^{-1} \implies x = y $$

Second, surjectivity: take an element $g \in G^*$. We need to find there exists $a \in G$ such that $\phi(a) = g $. Just take $a = g^{-1} $

Finally, you need to check it presesves the operation

$$ \phi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = \phi(b)  \phi(a) =_{[by \; hypothesis]} \phi(a) * \phi(b)$$

therefore, you have an isomorphism

Comment: It's an involution (i.e. inverse to itsself), no need to show injectivity and surjectivity ...

Comment: maybe the asker does not know what an involution is.

Comment: Yeah, I have never herd of involution. We have never talked about that in class before.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If $f$ is a map satisfying $f \circ f  =\mathrm{id}$, then $f$ is inverse to itsself, hence bijective. It is somehow unnatural and a waste of time to show injectivity and surjectivity if we have an explicit inverse map.

Comment: However, the asker said he does not know what involution mean. You are confusing the asker.

Comment: I feel like the code here is missing some content. Is it really this straight and to the point?

Comment: yeah. very simple

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In $G$ we have $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$.